# character of induced representation and the lifting representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

$A:H\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is a representation. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We define the lifting $\overline A(\sigma)=A(\sigma)$ if $\sigma\in H$, $\overline A(\sigma)=0$ if $\sigma\in G-H$.

I read from a book that the character

$\chi^{A\uparrow^G_H}(\tau)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{\sigma\in G}\chi^{\overline A}(\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1})$.

The author cited this result directly but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: This is a standard computation. You can find it here, for example: http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/characters-of-induced-representations/

Comment: Well, how is that character defined in that book? And what book is it? I don't think I have seen such a complicated notation for this before.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : This is not complicated. Usually, instead of defining $\chi^{\overline A}$, people write $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} \in H$ under the sum and write $\chi(\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1})$ as a summand. (The question is pretty old, but I thought I'd clarify for readers bumping in the question.)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva The reason I consider this complicated (compared to what it needs to be) is that they actually define this "lift" on the representation itself at first, even though this means that $\overline{A}$ is now no longer a representation (it does not even take values in invertible matrices). So the notation $\chi^{\overline{A}}$ is a bit misleading since it is not actually a character.